# Visual Stuio 2022 17.5.4.Maui and no MAC connection

Tags: ios, macos, maui, visual-studio-2022

someon else questioned MAUI and connecting to a Mac. I did add my experiences of similar thing
I have successfully connected to a MAC. Ive recently done a complete reinstall of VS to latest version ditto VS for MAC so all workloads should be there and xcode validates
This time the connection fails when
"Installing pack Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.osx-x64.Cross.ios-arm version 6.0.16..."
after an apparent timeout I get the error
"dotnet validation failed, an unexpected error occurred
The client vs14548john has been disconnected while waiting a post response to topic xvs/idb/initialize-dotnet-workload"
I have tried deleting obj and bin and .vs folders - are there other caches ? I cant help thinking its flakey old MAUI yet again - one spends 10 times the amount of time onits glitches than writing your own code

I CAN connect to the same MAC if I set up a Xamarin Forms project.

Can anyone help please?   I only write for 'pro bono' and club things nothing commercial but this is stopping ALL progress

Answer (score 0):

If there is a problem during the "Installing", "Uploading", or "Starting" steps for any of Mac agents, you may try this solution: [*Clearing the Broker, IDB, Build, and Designer Agents on the Mac*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/troubleshooting#clearing-the-broker-idb-build-and-designer-agents-on-the-mac) (This doc is about Xamarin and it applies to MAUI). You could delete the **XMA** folder for **both Windows and Mac** just as above link said and this will force Visual Studio to re-upload them.

Then restart Visual Studio and pair to Mac again.

Hope it works.